# BI Platform REST API: add to favorite folder?

Tags: rest, business-objects-sdk

I'm redeveloping a Crystal Reports UI using the Business Intelligence Platform REST API (4.2 SP5), and I'm finding some gaps in the API.

The one I'm stumbling over now is how to add a report to a user's favorites folder.  I can find the user's folder by querying with the `/v1/cmsquery` endpoint, but I can't take that id and use it in the `/infostore/###/children` endpoint.  And I also can't figure out how to take an existing report from that infostore tree and create a shortcut to it in the user's folder.  (Which appears to be how the favorites folder works, under the hood.)

Any direction -- particularly to good documentation or examples -- would be helpful.  I was already looking at [the developer guide](https://help.sap.com/viewer/db6a17c0d1214fd6971de66ea0122378/4.2.5/en-US/45aaec876e041014910aba7db0e91070.html), but it's pretty limited.

(Edit for typos)

Comment: You want to create a new document, or move an existing document to Favorites?

Comment: I'm talking about existing documents, but "moving" isn't quite accurate.  Looking at the `\infostore` endpoint, it appears that the process is creating a shortcut to the document, in the user-favorite folder.

Comment: They are two different actions -- you can definitely move a document from folder to folder (including from a public folder to personal, or vice-versa), or you can create a shortcut and put that shortcut anywhere.

Comment: ...or copy a document to another folder.  It works exactly like files/folders/shortcuts in Windows.

Comment: Do you have an example of how it's done?  REST calls, verbs, content?  I'm trying to figure this out and coming up with nothing in the documentation.

Comment: There's not a whole lot, but there are some articles on SCN.  Here's one: https://blogs.sap.com/2013/09/05/scripting-web-intelligence-the-restful-raylight-web-services/